# Teaching myself OOP in C++

Tags: oop, parameter-passing, instantiation

So I've been working on this program for the last month. The original code is from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjHKwCZyAhQ&list=PLHm_I0tE5kKPPWXkTTtOn8fkcwEGZNETh&index=3

However, I thought I would turn it into an object oriented program before I went on. Doing rather than copying is the best way to learn. The code generated a bmp file before i divided it up, but not anymore. The program executes but it doesn't create a file. Additionally I added Hello World in my .cpp files to see if they were even being executed and it looks like they aren't. I realize in copying this that I have a lot of code, I think the problem is in the main file so hopefully if anyone is nice enough to help me they can pick it out much more quickly!

*edit
Also in the original code he had the strut as a global variable but wasn't sure which file to implement it in or even how to make something global in an OOP! Would I just put it in main above int main() ?

**Output.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ProProcess.h" //this is just a bunch of preprocessor directives

//this program creats a single color bmp file using red, blue, and green (rgb)

class OutPut 
{
public:

OutPut(const int height, std::string file_name, int dpi, int index);
~OutPut();

//savebmp_str(std::string* file_name, const int width, const int height, int dpi, int pixels, struct RGBtype); 
//commented this out because I wasn't sure how I should pass all these values. Ultimately I used OutPut Object_Output in bmp.cpp so that these variables could be passed in there



const int Getwidth() { return width; }
const int Setwidth(const int x) { const int width =  x; }

private:
struct RGBtype  //Could be a global variable but I dont know which file to put it in
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

};

const int width = 1960; //window size
const int height = 1080;
int dpi = 72;
int number_of_pixels = width*height;
int index;
const char* file_name = "Scene.bmp";
RGBtype *pixels = new RGBtype[number_of_pixels];//creates an array so   that each pixel is comprised of a mix of rgb
```

};

**Output.cpp**

```
#include "OutPut.h"
#include "ProProcess.h"

OutPut::OutPut(const int height, std::string file_name, int dpi, int index) 
{
 OutPut::RGBtype color;


for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) //nested for loop that draws out each pixel totalling 1920x1080 in all
{

    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) 
    {
        index = y*height + x;
    pixels[index].r = 311;//changing the number here changes the color
    pixels[index].g = 311;
    pixels[index].b = 311;
    }

}

std::cout << "Hello World";
}

OutPut::~OutPut()
{

}
```

**BMP.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ProProcess.h"
#include "OutPut.h"


struct RGBtype
{
int r;
int g;
int b;

};

class BMP
{
public:
BMP(const char *filename, int passed_width, int passed_height, int dpi, RGBtype* data);

~BMP();

private:
OutPut Object_Output(std::string* file_name, const int width, const int height, int dpi, int pixels, struct RGBtype);//this is to pass the variables declared in output.h so bmp.h and bmp.cpp can use them too. Not sure how I would even verify i am doing this properly!

//const char* savebmp_str();
int passed_width;
int passed_height;
int dpi;


RGBtype *data;

};
```

**BMP.cpp**

```
#include "BMP.h"
#include "ProProcess.h"
#include "OutPut.h"




BMP::BMP(const char *filename, int passed_width, int passed_height, int dpi, RGBtype *data)
{

std::cout << passed_height;
    FILE *pFile;
    int k = passed_width*passed_height;
    std::cout << "The value k is" << k;
    int s = 4 * k;
    int filesize = 54 + s; //s is a function of width and height

    double factor = 39.375;
    int m = static_cast<int>(factor);

    int ppm = dpi*m;

    unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = { 'B','M',0,0,0,0 ,0,0,0,0, 54,0,0,0 }; //B and M are case sensitive. They make a bmp file
    unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = { 40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0 ,0,0,0,0, 1,0,24,0 };// the header size 14 and 40 are part of the BMP format



    bmpfileheader[2] = (unsigned char)(filesize);
    bmpfileheader[3] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 8);
    bmpfileheader[4] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 16);
    bmpfileheader[5] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[4] = (unsigned char)(passed_width);
    bmpinfoheader[5] = (unsigned char)(passed_width >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[6] = (unsigned char)(passed_width >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[7] = (unsigned char)(passed_width >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[8] = (unsigned char)(passed_height);
    bmpinfoheader[9] = (unsigned char)(passed_height >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[10] = (unsigned char)(passed_height >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[11] = (unsigned char)(passed_height >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[21] = (unsigned char)(s);
    bmpinfoheader[22] = (unsigned char)(s >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[23] = (unsigned char)(s >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[24] = (unsigned char)(s >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[25] = (unsigned char)(ppm);
    bmpinfoheader[26] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[27] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[28] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[29] = (unsigned char)(ppm);
    bmpinfoheader[30] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[31] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[32] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 24);

    pFile = fopen(filename, "wb");

    fwrite(bmpfileheader, sizeof(char), 14, pFile);
    fwrite(bmpinfoheader, sizeof(char), 40, pFile);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        RGBtype rgb = data[i];
        double red = (data[i].r);
        double green = (data[i].g);
        double blue = (data[i].b);

        int color[3] = { (int)floor(blue), (int)floor(green), (int)floor(red) };

        fwrite(color, 1, 3, pFile);

    }
    fclose(pFile);
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}




BMP::~BMP()
{
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "OutPut.h"
#include "ProProcess.h"
#include "BMP.h"

int main()
{
OutPut Pixel_gen();               
BMP BMP_Format_Maker();
OutPut Object_Output();



system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```